# Using Xcode 11.4.1, Why do these errors show in the animation part?

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

Why am I getting these errors when I try to call the animation function, `handleTapAnimation()`, inside of `viewDidLoad()`? I provided a relevant screenshot below the code snippet.

For reference, I am using Xcode 11.4.1 as my IDE.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  // Other methods

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupLabel()
    setupStackView()

    //animation
    view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,
                                                     action: #selector(handleTapAinmation)))

  }
  @objc fileprivate func handleTapAnimation() {
    print ("Animating")

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {


      self.titleLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -30, y: 0)


    }) { (_) in
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

        self.titleLabel.alpha = 0
        self.titleLabel.transform =
        self.titleLabel.transform.translatedBy(x: 0,y: -200)

      })
    }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

      self.titleLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -30, y: 0)

    }) { (_) in
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.5, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

        self.bodyLabel.alpha = 0
        self.bodyLabel.transform =
          self.bodyLabel.transform.translatedBy(x: 0,y: -200)

      })
    }
  }
```

[image: Error Photo]

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You’ve made a mistake with the curly braces (at some point before the screen shot).

Comment: Ainmation != Animation

Answer (score 0):

just copy the line 46 and paste it into viewdidload()
and put the handleTapAnimation() func to the viewcontroller class because you wrote it outside the viewcontroller as iguess